# Lagrange's equation for system not having time translation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, time, variational-principle

While we are deriving Lagrange's equation from D'Alembert's principle, when we argues as;

> $$\delta \vec r_\alpha = \sum_i \frac{\partial \vec r_\alpha}{\partial
>  q_i }\delta q_i +  \frac{ \partial \vec r_\alpha}{\partial t } \delta
>  t ,$$ but since a virtual displacement takes no time, $\delta t =0$

However, $\delta t$ is a virtual time translation, not a real one, similar to $\delta \vec r$ is a virtual displacement, not a real one.

However, in most of the applications, we are free to choose the time $t = t_0$ arbitrarily, but not all systems have such time translation, so in that case, shouldn't we not ignore that factor $\delta t$ also ?

**Edit:**

$\delta r_\alpha$ stands for the virtual displacement in the position of the particle $\alpha, and in general $\delta$ is used for a virtual change.

Comment: To avoid confusion, consider to provide references and definitions.

Comment: @Qmechanic see my edit; I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW,

1. The concept of [virtual displacements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement) in classical mechanics is defined with frozen time $\delta t=0$ whether or not the system has explicit time dependence.
2. We usually assume that [D'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) holds holds for *all* times $t$, not just for particular values of time $t$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but we **assume** that the virtual displacement happens in a frozen **real** time $d t = 0$; not $\delta t  = 0$. $\delta$ stands for a virtual change.

Comment: FWIW, $t$ is time, not the parameter for a virtual displacement.

Comment: I'm aware of that.

Comment: How do you define $dt$ vs. $\delta t$?

Comment: 1. $dt$ is the change in time that we can actually measure. 2. $\delta t$ is the time required for the system to cover $\delta r$ distance.

Comment: 1. No comment at this point. 2. No, $\delta t=0$ even if $\delta r\neq 0$.